# I have a modal that opens a second modal and cannot close the first modal if open then close the second

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, modal-dialog

To start I created a [codepen](http://codepen.io/garrettmac/pen/VerOWQ/) and I think the title says it all. I created a service to handle my modals, as seen here

```
.service('ModalService', function($ionicModal, $ionicLoading, $rootScope) {
    var init = function(tpl, $scope) {
      $ionicLoading.show({
        content: 'Loading',
        animation: 'fade-in',
        showBackdrop: true,
        maxWidth: 200,
        showDelay: 0
      });

      var promise;
      $scope = $scope || $rootScope.$new();
      promise = $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(tpl, {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
      }).then(function(modal) {
        $scope.modal = modal;
        return modal;
      });
      $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        $scope.modal.remove();
      });
      return promise;
    }
    return {
      init: init
    }
  })
```

and it gets called in the controller  like so

```
   ModalService.init('modal.html', $scope).then(function(modal) {
        ...do something....
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        modal.show();
      });
```

The issue it that I can only close one modal, the first one or the second, but if I go into the second I cannot close the second. Im assuming when I close one its destroying the modal instance for both? How can I work around this if I do not want to slit it into different controllers?

Comment: Do you want the first modal to close and then the second modal to open??

Comment: I'd like them both to be able to close if I navigate into the second, but when I navigate into the second and close it (returning to the second) it makes the first modals close button unresponsive

Comment: no im using the ionic framework

Comment: I think this may help : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/multiple-controllers-per-view-global-app-controller-wtf-is-a-controller/1070/3

Comment: use timeout function to close the modal box automatically after 2 or 3 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assigned all the instances of `modal` controller returned by `$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(...).then(modal)` function to $scope.modal.

The second instance "overwrites" the first one, so when you close the 2nd and then try to hide the first one using the close button (`ng-click="modal.hide()"`) `$scope.modal` still points to the 2nd...

So, in your Service you have to store modal controller individually for each instance of $ionicModal.
Here is a possible edit to your code:

http://codepen.io/beaver71/pen/dGKBmv

Check also this post: [How to create two ionic modal in a cordova app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29969588/how-to-create-two-ionic-modal-in-a-cordova-app)
or this one: [Ionic Multiple Modals only last showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33467059/ionic-multiple-modals-only-last-showing)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for taking the time and sharing

Comment: Thanks again for your help, however how does this work when using libraries modal? I seem to have a problem having any of then be responsive and formulated this into another question I created here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35474491/i-created-a-service-to-handle-modals-however-when-clicking-content-in-a-nested. Thanks again, thought you may know